# How come YouTube ads do not load on default Android web browser?

Tags: youtube

I am confused when ads show up on Android browsers. [This video](http://youtu.be/rUVH1cC7W1Q) for example is configured to show ads all the time before the video starts:

But it doesn't show that on my Android browser, but does show the ads on the web. Would anyone know why that happens?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using stock ROM or custom ROM? Do you have any ad blocker installed?

Comment: It is entirely dependant on what you are running. I get them on my unrooted S4. You may have ad-block or similar running.

Comment: @RossC hmmm..you get the ads on the video I posted in this question? Interesting...I don't think I have any ad blocker running. At least I didn't install one.